# gatsby is not working after installing windows 10 and latest NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, gatsby

I have created gatsby project as instructed in official website of gatsbyjs but it's not working.

NodeJS version: v16.15.0,
npm version: 8.8.0,

gatsby version: 4.13.0,
gatsby CLI version: 4.13.0

```
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\my-app>npm run develop

> gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop
> gatsby develop

C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\my-app\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\my-app\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\artifacts\index.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\my-app\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\index.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\New folder\my-app\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\dist\node.js:14:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Comment: did you run first `npm install`?

Comment: I think there is no need to do that, because I have created gatsby project using `gatsby new [app name]` , though I have tried that also

Comment: maybe try delete node_modules folder and then run `npm i`

Comment: I have tried that also

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 10 and Node v16.15.1. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `package-lock.json`, your `node_modules` and run the `npm install` again.

If the issue persist try:

- Bumping your `gatsby-cli` version
- Downgrading your Node version (since you are in the latest LTS)
- Switching to `yarn`

Related resources/workarounds:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23378
- https://lifesaver.codes/answer/cli-yoga-layout-prebuilt-error-on-gatsby-build-24577
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24577